# Как решается задача квадратичного программирования?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Я пытаюсь понять метод опорных векторов при линейно неразделимой выборке. Нашел информацию, что задача метода опорных векторов эквивалентна двойственной задаче поиска седловой точки функции Лагранжа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее при помощи условия Куна-Таккера эту задачу сводят к задаче квадратичного программирования.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не нашел в интернете понятного объяснения решения задачи квадратичного программирования. На всех сайтах, что я посетил, ссылаются на уже готовые библиотеки, но мне не нужна программная реализация. Мне нужно понять как решается эта задача. Желательно простыми словами или ссылкой на какой-нибудь источник, где это рассказывалось бы.

Comment: Подсказываю. Что бы понять, как решается эта задача надо не интернет-статейки искать, а прочитать учебник, где это описыватся строго, последовательно, с объяснениями и так, что-бы это можно было понять. Простота слов при этом определяется тем, на кого направлен учебник -  но тут уже выбирать вам, мы ваш уровень подготовки не знаем.  Ищите по словам "исследование операций", "нелинейное программирование",  "квадратичное программирование", "методы оптимизации". Переписывать сюда раздел учебника специально для вас врят-ли кто будет.